# Want to disable/remove selected item from a dynamically created dropdownlist in mvc razor

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, razor

I have created dynamic dropdownlistfor which run in for loop.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-primary text-center">Source Table</th>
            <th class="text-primary text-center">Destination Table</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for (i = 0; i < Model.mapTables.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.mapTables[i].sourceColumn, new SelectList(Model.sourceSelectList, "Text", "Value"), new {@id = "source", @class = "form-control",@onchange = "test3()"  })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.mapTables[i].targetColumn, new SelectList(Model.desTinationSelectList, "Text", "Value"), new { @class = "form-control" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It creates a ui like below:

[image: Dropdownlist]

all the row has same items in the dropdownlistfor. Now if i select a item named "AssestId" then "AssestId" item will be disabled/removed from the next dropdownlistfor. So that it can not be selected again.

i am unable to find any solution to do that. It would great help if someone can point me to a right path to do that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S10NTbtG1-78JAMI9mkjzi7imar2aOV7/view?usp=sharing)

This is the image link for the UI

Comment: You can select particular element by $(this) and then you can disable or remove that via ajax call or anything.

Comment: @Rush.2707 it would be great help if you can share some code sample. Thank you

Comment: I am unable to select the dynamic id of the dropdownlist and selected index of that dropdownlist

Comment: I think it's hard or impossible to realize it. I wrote a detailed explanation below so that you may understand my meaning better since I know it can't be known as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`will be disabled/removed from the next dropdownlistfor`, per my searching, we can't make specific options to be disabled since there's no option/attribute can be used on options, so we can only try to remove the options, but it's also difficult.

First, we have to add onchange event for each dropdown list right? And in the dropdown list, we also have to try to remove options for each one. So if you can say, ok I will only have 3 dropdown, then you may try code like this:

You have to identify different id for each dropdown so that you can bind onchange event for them, then getting the target value of the option then remove it in the other selectors.

```
<tbody>
        @for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.author, new SelectList(listItems, "Text", "Value"), new {@id = "source"+i, @class = "form-control"  })
                </td>
                <td>
                    asdf
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $('#source0').change(function(){
            alert($(this).children('option:selected').val());
            var p1=$(this).children('option:selected').val();
            $('#source1 option[value='+p1+']').remove();  
        })
    </script>
}
```